# Do enough permutations of an initial set probably cover most permutations?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, st.statistics, it.information-theory

Fix $\alpha, \epsilon \in(0,1)$. Take $(S_n)_n$ to be any sequence of sets with each $S_n$ containing $ \lceil (n!)^\alpha\rceil$ permutations of $n$ elements. Also build another sequence of sets $(S_n^\ast)_n$ by, for each $S^\ast_n$, drawing $\lceil (n!)^{1-\alpha+\epsilon} \rceil$ permutations uniformly at random. Is it true that $|\{\pi \circ \pi^\ast: \pi\in S_n, \pi^\ast \in S_n^\ast\}|/n! \to 1$ in probability?

Comment: by "with high probability", do you mean "almost surely"?

Comment: i didn't mean that in the original post but i guess it is true

Comment: what does "with high probability" mean?

Comment: sorry,  i misspoke. meant  converges "in probability" not "with high probability"

Comment: I guess I could have meant something by "with high probability"... it could have been that there was a sequence of $S_n$ put together so that the quotient only goes to 1 with probability $f(\alpha,\varepsilon)< 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M_n$ is all permutations of $n$ elements then $\{\pi \circ S_n: \pi \in M_n\}$ is precisely a $|S_n|$-fold cover of $M_n$. Choosing $S_n^\ast$ and then forming the composition of $S_n^\ast$ with $S_n$ is like sampling this cover. The log  likelihood that $\pi\in M_n$ is not covered by the composition is $\log((1-|S_n|/n!)^{|S_n^\ast|})=\log(1-|S_n|/n!)|S_n^\ast|=[-|S_n|/n! + O((|S_n|/n!)^2)]|S_n^\ast|$ which $\to -\infty$ if $|S_n||S_n^\ast|/n!\to \infty$, so the OP is true almost surely, not just in probability.